# Calling in indexes in session variables

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to do this for a few days, and I cant seem to find anything on the net about it, but then again I am not really sure what I should be searching, plus it may not even be possible.

So I have a form which is looped dependent on how many parcels they wish to send, I loop the names using the index in the loop, as you can see below. so it goes like 'Weight . $i' = 'Weight1' and so on...

I then stores these into session variables, but now I want to pull through all the session variables for those that are set, and I wanted to be able to loop through the session variables as I am trying to display like a summary page of all the parcel details, as shown in below code?

I have sessions called PWE1, PWE2 etc and want it to loop through them rather than calling them individually.

Is this possible? if so how?

```
<h4>Parcel Details</h4>
<?php
if($SV != null){
$i = 0;

do {
  $i++;
?>

<h3>Parcel <?php echo $i;?> </h3>

<p> Weight: <?php echo $_SESSION['PWE' . echo $i  ]; ?> </p>

<?php 

} while ($i != $SV);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a 2d array and loop through it?

```
// store your PWE1, PWE2 etc in here
$_SESSION["weights"]["PWE1"] = $value;
$_SESSION["weights"]["PWE2"] = $value2;
$_SESSION["weights"]["PWE3"] = $value3;

$i = 0;

foreach($_SESSION["weights"] as $pwe) {

    echo '<h3>Parcel' . $i . '</h3>';

    echo '<p>Weight:' . $pwe . '</p>';

    $i++;
};
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I didn't even know you could do that, wish I had known from the start now!! thank you again! works perfectly!